# How to correctly connect swagger definition to a subfolder of the deployed app to the hosting

Tags: c#, iis, deployment, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .net core web api application with swagger.

I'm using .net 5

**Infrastructure:**

I'm using smarterasp hosting services for react app and webapi app.
React app is on the root of the created (folder) website.
I just moved my webapi from my root folder to the folder `api`.

*Note:* the webapi worked ok, when it was initially in the root folder.

**Problem:**

As I mentioned, when I moved my webapi to the `api` subfolder, I'm getting the error:

[image: Screenshot]

**Attempts:**

I tried to change address in my Startup.cs class:

- ./swagger/v1/swagger.json
- api/swagger/v1/swagger.json

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
{
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("./swagger/v1/swagger.json", "NNN.WebApi v1");
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });
       ...
}
```

but, I'm getting or this failure message or 404 not found..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
{
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "NNN.WebApi v1");
            
        });
       ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put following endpoint:
`c.SwaggerEndpoint("/v1/swagger.json", "NNN.WebApi v1");`